# How to make client PC work independently from Server

Tags: database, security, design-patterns, web-applications, database-design

(Sorry, I don't know exactly should I ask this question here in stackoverflow or other related sites. please move it if isn't appropriate)

There are some unrelated groups of students which each group members produce data together. each member use his credentials to login to the client desktop application  and send data to the server. other group members should see new data if they login with their credentials.

The problem comes in when I want to make the client works although there was an error in connection to the server. I don't want to stop them if they couldn't connect to server, so they make data and later will send it to server.

**here is the problem, without connecting to the server, how can I make memberships in the client and be sure he really belongs to the group, or how can I know other member has new data in the local machine so his collegues can see it?**

I don't want to use another local server, just a remote server and a local machine with database.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is unavailable, the only way to know if a person is in a group is if you have that information stored on the client. Of course, someone could be removed from a group and the (disconnected) client does not know it.

Solving this would depend on how your system is used.

1. If membership does not change very often, you could use the client-saved membership as long as it is not too old (e.g. use it if it is less than 4 hours old, or some such rule).
2. Whenever the client re-connects to the server, it should ensure that its local data is refreshed if it older than N-hours
3. In addition, when the connection is re-established, and the data is sent to the server, the server should check once more. if the user has been removed from a group, the server can reject the data